# Facing a SMTP ERROR on phpmailer all of a sudden

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

My PHPMAILER script has been working fine until couple days ago with the following message - nothing has changed as far as I am aware
Any idea ?
Thanks

```
SSL loaded Server -> Client: +OK <30126.1635064119@pop.w14.httpserveur.net> Server -> Client: +OK Server -> Client: +OK Server -> Client:
debug level 3; message: Connection: opening to ssl://46.105.44.1:465, timeout=300, options=array()
debug level 3; message: Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [/home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 394]
debug level 3; message: Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 394]
debug level 3; message: Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://46.105.44.1:465 (Unknown error) [/home/clients/cineferte.fr/http/mail/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 394]
debug level 1; message: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
debug level 3; message: SMTP connect() failed.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: Here’s a clue: `certificate verify failed`. Now go and read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide which covers this in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I will investigate in this direction. 
Difficult to understand why the SSL certificate failed - it is still valid, !

Comment: This has nothing to do with your own certificate, only Outlook’s, and your CA bundle. But of course you know that, having read the guide, right?

Comment: sarcasm, sarcasm...it feels like you really enjoy helping others

Comment: Since I wrote the code, the guide, and answered over a thousand questions on this, I guess I do.